# Entity Framework 5/6 support for WPF with related tables

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I was wondering if anyone has the same issue I'm having getting Entity framework 5/6 to work with WPF
dotnet 4.5 and Visual studio 2013. It seems like Microsoft are dropping their support for WPF.

Well the main issue I'm having is getting data from some related tables and present it on two DataGrids.
while still being able to modify the data on the two DataGrids, I'm able to query the data in many different
ways and i can successfully populate it on the two DataGrids but i can't modify or add new records 
to one of the two DataGrids.  Usually this was straight forward and very easy using Entity Framework 4.
Here is how i populate the Data on the CollectionViewSource:

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {

                managerMEntities = new ManagerMEntities();

                billViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource (this.FindResource("billViewSource")));


                managerMEntities.Bills.Load();

                billViewSource.Source = managerMEntities.Bills.Local;

            }
```

With Entity Framework 4 we were able to include the related data like this :

```
           ObjectQuery billsQuery = managerMEntities.Bills;
           billsQuery.Include("Products");
```

but that's not possible anymore with Entity Framework 5/6

when i click the second DataGrid i get this error message 
"{"'EditItem' is not allowed for this view."}"

as you can see the second DataGrid is completely inactive.

![DataGrid the second DataGrid is completely inactive.][1]

Here is the XAML for the DataGrid, It's just testing DataGrid generated 
using Visual studio by dragging and dropping the Data structure from 
the Data Source to the XAML designer.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="billViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Bill}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="billProductsViewSource" Source="{Binding Products, Source={StaticResource billViewSource}}"/>

</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource billViewSource}" >
    <DataGrid x:Name="billDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,10,287,0" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Height="287" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="b_commentColumn" Binding="{Binding b_comment}" Header="b comment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="b_dateColumn" Header="b date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding b_date, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="b_idColumn" Binding="{Binding b_id}" Header="b id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="b_NumberColumn" Binding="{Binding b_Number}" Header="b Number" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="b_totalColumn" Binding="{Binding b_total}" Header="b total" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="productsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource billProductsViewSource}}" Margin="10,319,205,0" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Height="258" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="bill_b_idColumn" Binding="{Binding bill_b_id}" Header="bill b id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_codeColumn" Binding="{Binding p_code}" Header="p code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_commentColumn" Binding="{Binding p_comment}" Header="p comment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_descriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding p_description}" Header="p description" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_idColumn" Binding="{Binding p_id}" Header="p id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_price_totalColumn" Binding="{Binding p_price_total}" Header="p price total" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_price_unitColumn" Binding="{Binding p_price_unit}" Header="p price unit" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="p_quantityColumn" Binding="{Binding p_quantity}" Header="p quantity" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If MS is dropping support from WPF it will surprise quite a few people! You need to give a bit more info about the DataGrids, such as how they are defined and what in.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't use `ObjectQuery` in EF 5/6?